# discord.js resolve function

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I made a bot in discord.js v12 and want to update it to v13. While updating it, I noticed that `client.resolveChannel`, `client.resolveMember` etc. are no longer working, so I'm guessing that they removed it but if they didn't what is the current resolve function? If it got removed, how can you easily resolve a member with `args` preferably like this as you did in v12?

```js
let user = await client.resolveMember(message.guild, args[0]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use these:

```js
client.resolveMember(message.guild, args[0])
```

should be either [`GuildMemberManager#resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=resolve) or [`GuildMemberManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch):

```js
let user = message.guild.members.resolve(USER_ID)

// OR

let user = await message.guild.members.fetch(USER_ID)
```

Similarly

```js
client.resolveChannel(message.guild, args[0])
```

should be either [`ChannelManager#resolve`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=resolve) or [`ChannelManager#fetch`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/ChannelManager?scrollTo=fetch)

```js
let channel = message.guild.channels.resolve(CHANNEL_ID)

// OR

let channel = await message.guild.channels.fetch(CHANNEL_ID)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Guild.members.resolve()`

```js
let user = message.guild.members.resolve(args[0])
```

Comment: Oops, you were faster :)

Comment: oh wow didnt know it was that easy, thank you